# VBS Scripting Error

Tags: vbscript, compilation

I apologize in advance for my "newness" to vbs. I am trying to run this script to search for all pst files on my file server. At this point, I am getting this error:

searchpst.vbs(6, 26) Microsfot VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement.

the script I am trying to run is of course named searchpst.vbs, and I know the (6, 26) is the line and charecter number of the error, but I cant seem to figure out what to do to fix it? Below is my script, and help is greatly appreciated!

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
strsql = "Select" * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = '"pst"'"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set wfile = fso.opentextfile("c:\test.csv",2,true)

For Each objFile in colFiles

    Wfile.writeline(strComputer & " " & objFile.Drive & " " & objFile.Path & " " & objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension & " " & objFile.FileSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted the code for easier readability.  The single apostrophe `'` changes everything behind it into a comment, so it's not part of the code.  So `'"pst"'"` isn't visible.

Actually, there are more problems than just that.  That whole line is formatted incorrectly, and I think you've got a couple other lines out of order.  It should look like this, I think:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
strsql = "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'pst'"
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strsql)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set wfile = fso.opentextfile("c:\test.csv",2,true)

For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wfile.writeline(strComputer & " " & objFile.Drive & " " & objFile.Path & " " & objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension & " " & objFile.FileSize)
Next
```

Comment: Joe, thanks a million! It worked perfectly. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You need param list (), if you call a function to receive its return value; and _ continues a line - so change:

```
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
strsql = "Select" * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = '"pst"'"
```

to

```
strsql = "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'pst'"
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strsql)
```

or:

```
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
     "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'pst'")
```

After reading @Joe's (+1) answer, I tried to clean up the quoting in your SQL.